# Method chaining without parentheses, how to?

Tags: c#, class, object, methods, chain

I would like to do a method chain, for example like this:

```
Car myCar = new Car();

// Chaining
myCar.config.engine.cylinders("4");
```

But how do I do the chaining, without using parentheses in "config" or "engine"?

I can only figure out to do it like this:

```
myCar.config().engine().cylinders("4");
```

Comment: Have you tried properties ? :)

Comment: If you want to call a method, you have to use parentheses. If you have control over the class, you can define _properties_ instead of methods.

Comment: I think you are confusing methods & properties. In this case, I would use properties instead of methods.

Comment: @Ravi: Extension Methods? How would you fake them to look like a property?

Comment: check out this link [Fluent interfaces and Method Chaining in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640997/Fluent-interfaces-and-Method-Chaining-in-Csharp)

Comment: @Ravi: How can an extension method be called *without* the parantheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by declaring `Config` property in your `Car` class. Then `Engine` property in `CarConfig` class, like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public CarConfig Config { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can chain the calls.

Comment: An example with a read-only `Config` property, but with an explicitly written getter, might be more appropriate for this particular situation.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Or an auto-property with a private setter: `public CarConfig Config { get; private set; }`

Comment: Does "get" automatically return a new instance of the class CarConfig?

And what access modifier should the CarConfig class have?

Thanks.

Comment: The syntax of auto-properties is equivalent to:



    `private CarConfig _config;

    public CarConfig Config { 
        get { return _carConfig; }
        set { _carConfig = value; }
    }`

The `CarConfig` class should have the access modifier no less visible than the `Car` class. E.g. if `Car` class is public, `CarConfig` should be public as well. If `Car` is internal, `CarConfig` can be either public or internal. Actually, this is out of the current question's scope.

Comment: But does "get" actually make a "new" instance of the class CarConfig and returns it to the caller? I guess it does, since it would not be possible to access the properties and methods of CarConfig i you don't instantiate it? Is this correct?

Comment: No, `get` returns the already stored instance of `CarConfig`. You should initialize it somewhere (in constructor, for example). Maybe [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384054.aspx) will help you to get acquainted with auto-properties

Comment: Ok, now i understand. This seems to work with my chaining attempt: `public CarConfig config { get{return new CarConfig();} }` i just return the new instance in the get.

Answer (score 0):

You could use properties as many suggest, but this whole thing stinks of breaking the **[Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)** (or Principle of Least Knowledge). Basically you are breaking the encapsulation of the Car class. You may want to take a look at **[Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)**, especially the fluent implementations (like **[here](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2010/04/14/a-fluent-builder-in-c/)**).

Your code may then look like

```
Car myCar = new CarBuilder().WithEngineCylinders("4");
```