# Class to construct SCPI strings

Tags: c#, class, abstract-class, abstract

I am trying to write a class to form [SCPI commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Commands_for_Programmable_Instruments).  I'd like the usage to look like this (which is similar to what Keysight's DLL does):

```
Instrument.SCPI.DISPlay.TEXT.Command("HELLO");
```

which would then construct the string "DISP:TEXT HELLO" which I can send over a connection specified in the Instrument class.

I thought a static abstract class like this might work.  I could extend the class with new commands for any instrument I wish to support.  And an "Instrument" class based on the abstract SCPI class(es) could pass the resulting string to serial port or TCPIP or whatever.

```
public static class SCPI
{
    // Mandated commands
    public const string CLS = "*CLS";
    public const string ESE = "*ESE";
    public const string ESR = "*ESR";
    public const string IDN = "*IDN?";
    public const string OPC = "*OPC";
    public const string PSC = "*PSC";

    // Display command
    public static class DISPlay
    {
        public const string TEXT = "DISP:TEXT";
    }
}
```

But if I want to add the command "TEXT:CLEar" it immediately becomes unclear how to proceed, as I can't nest another class inside DISPlay with the name "TEXT".  How do I do this properly?  Specifically:

- How do I make the command strings build upon each other?
- How can I make a method to accept one or more arguments to be appended to the strings?
- Is there a convenient way of adding the required colon between strings?
- Is there a convenient way of adding a question mark at the end for queries?

Comment: Have a look here: https://elegantcode.com/2009/03/21/progressive-interfaces/

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242737/method-chaining-without-parentheses-how-to

Comment: The problem you face here is that I think you need to separate string generation from string definition, and to do that, I think you may have to abandon the `static` approach.

Comment: Oh, wow! I had no idea how method chaining worked, or even what it was called.

Comment: See also the Builder Pattern, and Fluent Interfaces.  That should be enough to get you started.  It's an interesting problem, but alas, I haven't the time to work on it right now.

Comment: You also might find [Irony](https://github.com/IronyProject/Irony) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

1. First solution: You can use decorator pattern in this case. Check the following link: 

    
    [decorator pattern tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCraGHx6gso)  

    

    
   To briefly explain how it applies to your case: 
   The SCPI protocol you can put root commands and branches and extend that until you have a well defined SCPI command:

```
ROOT:BRANCH1:BRANCH2 ... <parameters>
```

The following pseudo code shows how you can apply the pattern. Basically you need to assume that each command is a class that holds another command and returns a string as follows:

```
class COMMAND:  /* to be used as an interface for each SCPI command */
    COMMAND ref_to_deeper_commands = NULL 
    string command_str = ""
    string get_command(){
        if(ref_to_deeper_commands == NULL)
            return command_str
        else
            return command_str + ref_to_deeper_commands.get_string()
    }

class ROOT:COMMAND /*implementation of ROOT command*/
    ROOT(){
        command_str = ":ROOT"; 
    }

    ROOT(sub_commands){
        command_str = ":ROOT" 
        ref_to_deeper_commands = sub_commands 
    }


class BRANCH1:COMMAND /*implementation of BRANCH1 command*/
    ROOT(){
        command_str = ":BRANCH1"; 
    }

    ROOT(sub_commands){
        command_str = ":BRANCH1" 
        ref_to_deeper_commands = sub_commands 
    }

class BRANCH2:COMMAND /*implementation of BRANCH2 command*/
    ROOT(){
        command_str = ":BRANCH2"; 
    }

    ROOT(sub_commands){
        command_str = ":BRANCH2" 
        ref_to_deeper_commands = sub_commands 
    }
```

And you can implement the main function following this:

```
main_function(){
    COMMAND cmd = ROOT(BRANCH1(BRANCH2()))
    print cmd
}
```

calling the print function in the main code will give you:

```
ROOT:BRANCH1:BRANCH2
```

As you can see in the code above, you have the flexibility in making different command combinations. Parameters can also be passed to the innermost object instantiation.

2. Second solution: Given the limited number of SCPI commands (they are not so limited, but you do it once) you can create a library with functions to return proper strings and you only need to pass in parameters. The advantage is that you don't need to implements mechanisms to check validity of your commands, whereas in solution 1 you might end up making illegal strings not defined for you measurement device.